# MySQL recursive query for counting

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

i am trying to find a single query for my desired output and cannot get my head around it if it is at all possible..

table_forum:

```
forum_id    parent_id   forum_name
1           0           name1
2           1           name2
7           0           name3
8           7           name4
9           7           name5
173         9           name6
11          0           name7
12          0           name8
233         11          name9
14          11          name10
...
```

table_posts:

```
post_id topic_id    forum_id    poster_id
25626   61          1           85
2       1           1           85
3       1           1           85
4       1           1           85
5       1           1           85
6       1           1           85
7       200         7           85
8       19          8           85
9       4           9           85
10      2           173         85
196122  3202        233         85
11      2           173         85
12      2           173         85
...
```

I made a quick Fiddle for you to be able to test how far I came with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90b73f/1

Atm I can get one forum and all its parents with the posts counted upward but only from that forum upwards (no other forums get into the calculation)

What I would like to achieve is an sql output like this:

```
forum_id    forum_name  parent_id   lvl countPosts
1           name1       0           2   6
2           name2       1           1   0
7           name3       0           3   5
8           name4       7           2   1
9           name5       7           2   4
173         name6       9           1   3
11          name7       0           2   1
14          name10      11          1   0
233         name9       11          1   1
12          name8       0           1   0
```

I don't know if that's possible but I would like "lvl" to use later on as a counter for "\t" to indent the name of the forum, to better visualize on my site how the forums are assigned...

I want to later present it on the webpage in a table kind of like this (without bullet characters):

```
forumname       Postcount
name1           6
    name2       0
name3           5
    name4       1
    name5       4
        name6   3
etc...
```

If you have any better solution as to how you would approach the problem, I am all ears! - This is the first encounter with such a problem so I couldn't think of another way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer : no, mysql is not good for this kind of "recursive with N deep unknown", keeping the lvl at the insert could help you a lot with this kind of work

Comment: That answer might be too short however, as the tree seems to have a shallow and finite depth.

Comment: the deepest it ever gets is to 4 levels, so that's not possible then?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible.